# How to deal with chinese characters while writing csv with spark?

Tags: apache-spark, encoding

I have an encoding problem when i write a dataset (from parquet file) to csv.

the schema for the dataset looks like that :

```
 |-- 生效年月: long (nullable = true)
 |-- 再保编号: string (nullable = true)
 |-- µµµµ: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- çé_à: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- жжхцзояуфъ: long (nullable = true) 
 |-- 再保保单年度: long (nullable = true)
....
```

i tried to set encoding to utf-8 while reading the parquet / writing to csv file but no change :

```
sparkConnection.getSession().read()
        .option("sep", "")
        .option("header", true)
        .option("encoding", CharEncoding.UTF_8)
        .option("charset", CharEncoding.UTF_8)
```

all the Chinese chars are not good even after i setted the encoding to utf-8 :

[image]

and on notepad++ i have the correct result :

[image]

ps : in notepad++ i can see that the encoding is `ucs-2 le bom` not utf-8 even when i set encoding option while writing dataset to csv

I'm using spark 2.3.1 I tried also with version 3.0.0

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try open your file in Excel through Import? Like here: https://help.supportability.com.au/article/250-how-to-open-csv-files-safely-with-microsoft-excel. You can choose encoding during import.  

I can't test case with notepad++ on macbook, but with vscode everyting was fine. Encoding was detected as UTF-8 and file looked correct.

Comment: @ArtemAstashov Yes, I tried to import to excel and its working like that, but clients can't do that each time (it's the workaround used for now) I don't know if its an excel limitation

Comment: What is your usecase? You need to save csv and distribute to user? In this case maybe is option to import csv to excel, save it as xslx and send to users? In this case, xlsx file opens correct.